# Understanding Rosser's Theorem

Tags: logic, incompleteness

### Initial Situation

For some time now I'm trying to understand a proof for Rosser's Theorem -- the proof given in Smorynski's article "The Incompleteness Theorems" (here is a first entry from google: [The Incompleteness Theorems - Smorynski](http://www.compstat2004.cuni.cz/~krajicek/smorynski.pdf)), well actually it's not a proof but a list of hints -- and I'm struggling.

### The Definitions

**Rosser's Proof Predicate** is defined as an extension to the "usual" proof predicate in the following way:

$\newcommand{\Bew}[1]{\mathbf{Bew}_{\text{#1}}} \newcommand{\encode}[1]{\left\ulcorner #1 \right\urcorner}$
$$\Bew{PA}^R (x,y) \leftrightarrow \left(\Bew{PA}(x,y)\wedge \forall zw\leq x\left(\Bew{PA}(z,w)\rightarrow y\neq [\encode{\neg},w]\wedge w \neq [\encode{\neg},y]\right)\right).$$

(This is from page 841 -- I've just changed $\mathbf T$ to $\text{PA}$.)

And **Rosser's Theorem** is then stated as follows:

Let $\text{PA}\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \neg \exists x . \Bew{PA}^R(x,\encode{\varphi})$ and assume that $\text{PA}$ is consistent. Then

1. $\text{PA}\nvdash \varphi$;
2. $\text{PA}\nvdash \neg\varphi$;
3. $\text{PA}\vdash\text{Con}_{\text{PA}}^R$.

### Own ideas

First of all: it seems to me that Rosser's proof predicate is defined at first as a *primitive recursive relation*. If so, I agree with Smorynski here: it is extensional the same as $\Bew{PA}$ (seen as a primitive recursive relation), as long as we assume that $\text{PA}$ is consistent. Then, of course, 1. follows in the same way, as one can show it in the usual incompleteness theorem style ($\text{PA}\vdash\phi\Rightarrow \text{PA}\vdash\Bew{PA}^R(e,\encode{\phi})$ is the key, which holds then, for some closed term $e$.)

But then, I got some trouble showing 2. Since in my version, I need $\leq$ as a predicate in the language and not as a primitive recursive relation, or: I have to establish a connection from $\leq$ as primitive recursive relation to $\leq$ as a syntactical object. (I can give more details on that, but I think this is the wrong way anyways.)

Now, 3. seems clear to me, although my proof is a bit too meta for my taste.

### Questions

So, the big question is: how to proof 2. if one accept that $\Bew{PA}^R$ is defined as a primitive recursive relation at forehand? Especially with the following hint Smorynski gives: 2. follows from 3. Aha!

Or: How to proof 1, if one defines $\Bew{PA}^R$ as an extension to $\Bew{PA}$ in the syntactical world?

Or, second question one step further: how does one proof $\text{PA}\vdash\phi\Rightarrow \text{PA}\vdash\Bew{PA}^R(e,\encode{\phi})$, when $\Bew{PA}^R$ is seen syntactically?

Any ideas or hints, also solutions, are appreciated.  : )

Comment: You can see the full proof into Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZO1p4QGspoYC&pg=PA209) (4th ed - 1997), page 209-210; regarding point 2, the proof exploits some properties of the $\le$ relation.

Comment: Yeh, I had a look into his proof. He does, as far as I can see, define rosser's proof predicate purely syntactical. I'll have another look and see, if I can extrude the idea. Still I'm interested in the first question I stated.  : ). 

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I do not full grasp your concern ... Rosser's formula is a syntactical object; you are working in PA, i.e. first-order arithmetic, and thus you can simply add to the language the defined predicates $<$ and $\le$. Thus, in first-order language for arithmetic, $x \le y$ is a "well-formed" expression.

Comment: Well, my problem is the following (I might be missing something): Smorynski defines $\Bew{PA}^R$ as a primitive recursive relation. Of course, we then have $\Bew{PA}^R(x,y)\Leftrightarrow \text{PA}\vdash\color{red}{\Bew{PA}^R(\overline{x},\overline{y})}$ and so on, but I need some features of how $\Bew{PA}^R$ is defined, especially the $\forall wz\leq x$, to prove what I need to. But the $\color{red}{\Bew{PA}^R}$ is just a predicate symbol. I don't know nothing about it.

Comment: I see... In Mendelson' textbook, Godel and Rosser theorems are proved **after** a chapter deicated to "formal number theory" where, e.g. it is proved that $x < y$ is a primitive recursive relation and that relations obtained from p.r. relations by means of the conncetives **and** the *bounded quantifires* (like $\forall z \le x$) are p.r [see page 180].

Comment: I think that the issue is simply with Smorynski's article, which is an overview of results and not a textbook ... You need to complement it with a "full" textbook, like Mendelson, Enderton, Boolos & Burgess & Jeffrey or Tourlakis ...

Comment: So the idea is, that he does define it syntactical but in fact, it is componentwise primitive recursive, i.e. $\color{red}{\forall z \leq x. P(z)}$ is in the recursive world $\forall z \leq x : P(z)$?

Comment: Please, note that Smorynski's article has a misprint in page 841 (that you have reproduced); bullet 3. of Rosser's Th must be : $\mathsf PA \nvdash Con^R_{\mathsf PA}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Long comment*

**If** the issue is with $∀z≤x \ Pz$, we have to recall some definitions from :

- Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA213) (5th ed - 2013), page 213 :

> **Definition** A relation $R$ is *primitive recursive* if its characteristic function $\chi_R$ is so.
>
> The equality relation is p.r. : $\chi_=(x, y) = \overline {sg}(|x − y|)$
>
> The order relation is p.r. : $\chi_<(x, y) = \overline {sg}((x + 1) - y)$
>
> We say that $R$ is obtained by *bounded quantification* from $S$ if
>
> > $R(n,m) = Qx \le m \ S(n,x)$, where $Q$ is one of the quantifiers $∀,∃$.
>
> Consider the bounded existential quantification: $R(x,n) = ∃y \le n \ S(x, y)$; then $\chi_R(x,n) = sg(y \le n \ \chi_S(x, y))$, so if $S$ is primitive recursive, then $R$ is so.
>
> The $∀$ case is similar.

---

You can see also Smorynski's article itself, page 833 : for the relation of equality and bounded quantifiers.

In page 836 you can see how bounded quantifiers are used to define the representing functions for the syntactic notions of *term* and *formula*.

Finally [page 838], the bounded quantifier is used also in the definition of the $Prov_T(x,y)$ predicate.

Thus, in principle, nothing different happens with Rosser's predicate [page 841] : $Prov^R_T(x,y)$, which is simply "a little bit more complex".