# Closed term conditions in PA

Tags: logic, incompleteness

### The situation

I have to transfer statements from the "recursive world" into the "$\color{red}{\text{syntactical world}}$", in the context of binumerability of primitive recursive predicates into the theory $\newcommand{PA}{\color{red}{\text{PA}}} \PA$.

We have, as the main theorem:

Say $P(\cdot)$ is a primitive recursive relation. Then there exists a formula $\color{red}{\overline{P}}$ such that for every $x\in\mathbb{N}$, where $\color{red}{\overline{x}}$ is a corresponding closed term, i.e. $\color{red}{s ( s ( s ( \ldots 0 \ldots ) ) )}$,

(1) $P(x)\Leftrightarrow \color{red}{\PA\vdash\overline{P}(\overline{x})}$

(2) $\neg P(x)\Leftrightarrow \color{red}{\PA\vdash\neg\overline{P}(\overline{x})}$.

This means, one can transfer from one world to another *as long as one is talking about closed terms*.

### The question

Coming from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173205/understanding-rossers-theorem) question, I'm in the need to prove then the following:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \color{red}{\PA \vdash \exists x_1 w + x_1 = \overline{n}} \Rightarrow \exists k \in\mathbb{N} : \color{red}{\PA\vdash w = \overline{k}}$$

or in other words: if one assumes a closed term bound on a variable, one can then derive that it has to be a closed term also.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In Mendelson's book, page 165, you can find the related result : for any $k, \mathsf{PA}  \vDash w=0 \lor \ldots w= \overline k \leftrightarrow w \le \overline k$. The proof is by induction in the metalanguage on $k$.

Comment: Mendelson again. Thanks.  ; )

Comment: But also : Dirk van Dalen, Logic and Structure (5th ed - 2013), page 238, George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, Computability and Logic (5th ed - 2007), page 210, George Tourlakis, Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1 : Mathematical Logic (2003), page 183, Joseph Shoenfield, Mathematical Logic (1967), page 129.

Comment: In Smorynski's article, the necessary details are "hidden" (with a "little handwaving") in the formula of page 839 : If $f$ is p.r., (*) $fm_1 \ldots m_n=m \Rightarrow T \vdash f \overline {m_1} \ldots \overline {m_n} = \overline {m}$.